# Database for ecommerce application

Tags: database-design, e-commerce, database-schema

I have three types of products

```
 - Retail products (ID,product_categoryId,price,name)
 - Courses (ID,course_categoryId,price,name,roomId)
 - Events (ID,name,price,StartTime,EndTime)
```

All types have its own price. Should I create a single table for all mentioning the parent it or I have to create separate tables for each type?

Remember the user can buy multiple types. (For example she can by 2 retail products 3 course and one events). So the invoice is created in this way.

Kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create your tables like this (TSQL)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductTypes] (
    [Id] INT NOT NULL ,
    [Description] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products] (
    [Id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1) ,
    [ProductTypeId] INT NOT NULL, -- FK to ProductTypes table
    [Price] ...
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OrderItems] (
    [OrderId] INT NOT NULL ,
    [ProductId] INT NOT NULL
)

... and so forth?
```

Comment: the post edited. Kindly see the tables schema now. Each product type have different attributes. For example events have startDate and EndDate which other do not.